# Image showing behind 3rd party View in coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image in a coordinator layout and i have a diagonal layout i got from here - https://github.com/florent37/DiagonalLayout.

In the coordinator layout i am setting the Diagonal Layout as the anchor for the image cos i want my layout to look like the example in the url above.

here is my layout file and the result i am having

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.dishesteam.dishes.activities.ProfileActivity">

<com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
    android:id="@+id/diagonal_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:diagonal_angle="12"
    app:diagonal_direction="left"
    app:diagonal_position="bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_background">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Joshua Majebi"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/diagonal_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="left|bottom"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: diagonal]

My Image is falling behind the DiagonalLayout not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: try removing the `android:elevation="5dp"` from the `DiagonalLayout`..

Answer (score 0):

Elevation of `DiagonalLayout` is more higher than `ImageView`. So, you have to set higher elevation to `ImageView` to show it over `DiagonalLayout`.

Set `ImageView` elevation as `android:elevation="6dp"`

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
        android:id="@+id/diagonal_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:diagonal_angle="12"
        app:diagonal_direction="left"
        app:diagonal_position="bottom">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_background">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Joshua Majebi"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/diagonal_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="left|bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: Higher elevation in imageview will not work,,,,in api <21 means on Pre Lollipop devices it will not show!